PowerBI auto refresh for Jira data (dynamic)
I am hoping someone can help me with below problem.
I created a powerBi dashboard using dynamic data pulling directly from JIRA. Using api to authenticate and jql to query the data.
Within powerBi desktop, it works perfectly when I press the refresh button. However, when I publish my report, I can’t refresh manually nor set up an scheduled refresh.
Is there workaround? Not looking for paid services from marketplace.
Additionally, setting a gateway might not be that easy for me to organise with my org.
Thank you
I tried using an export and saving it in a SharePoint folder. The refresh and scheduled refresh works. It tells me that the problem is when my query is direct to JIRA.
